# CRM 2011 Workflow Create Record for 1 entity AND add existing record from another entity

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, workflow-activity

I have two custom entities; TRANSPORT ITEM and LOAD.

I want to be able to select a number of TRANSPORT ITEMS from a view and add them to a new LOAD.

I have the TRANSPORT ITEM entity added in a subgrid of the LOAD form.
Currently I can create a LOAD and then within the LOAD form, I can 'Add Existing Transport Items' which is fine, but I want to be able to do all of this as above.

I have been able to create an on-demand workflow, that when run against a TRANSPORT ITEM will create a new LOAD Item using the Transport Items values, but I can't get it to add the actual Transport Item as an existing Transport Item

Any help on how to do this within a workflow or jscript would be appreciated

Comment: The field "LOAD" on "TRANSPORT ITEM" is required?

Comment: Yes, I've added an extra step in my workflow to update a field LOAD on the TRANSPORT ITEM form with the Load ID. This now adds the Transport Item to the subgrid of Load Form as i wanted.

BUT, it only works for 1 item at a time. and if I create further Loads containing the previous Transport Item, the LOAD ID field is overwritten, so a Transport item can only be related to 1 load at a time

Comment: The first thing I need to know is: One load has a lot of transport item? 
`Load --> transport item`
OR a lot of loads have a lot of transport items? 
`Load <--> transport item`

Comment: A Load has a 1:N for TransportItems.
1 Load can have a number of separate TransportItems within it, but a TransportItem can only be linked to 1 load

I can have a number of Loads. Each of them with a number of TransportItems

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not able to understand you, please be patient with me. The problem: What you can't do? The moment: When you need this fire? The behavior: What you need to happen?

Comment: Hi, what i need is; when i select 2 or more TRANSPORT ITEMS from a list view, i want to create a new LOAD record, that automatically has the two selected Transport Items associated & displayed in the Transport Item subgrid within the Load